# One Web Application and working two Addresses URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

In ASP.NET MVC
How can I have a Website with two addresses URL on One Web Application
I don't know the configuration of the Web.Config File .One of the addresses is moved to HTTPS and one of the addresses is to HTTP only.
Thanks

Comment: Then learn what is site binding, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: I couldn't find where to put the settings in Web.Config File.thanks

Comment: It's not in web.config. It's configured in IIS. The XML in the linked article is part of the applicationhost.config file, but you should configure the bindings through the UI (Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager) to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to set multiple domain(address) to single web site? If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to use IIS management console to achieve your requirement.

You could open the IIS management console and right click the site and select edit bindings.

[image]

Then you could click add button on the binding window and type in your domain.

[image]

After added one binding and clicked OK button, you could click the add button to add the second https binding setting.

[image]